# AWS Cloudformation: Variable not interpolated in cfn-init command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In the following Cloudformation EC2 instance declaration:

```
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
      Comment: Test
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          commands:
            01_test:
              command: "echo \"${MyEndpoint}\" > /root/test.txt"
              cwd: "~"
```

The var `MyEndpoint` is never interpolated (the file created is empty).

Is it a syntax issue?

The variable certainly exists (it is used throughout the rest of the CF template with success)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above does not work.

One needs to use the `!Sub` function

```
  AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
    config:
      commands:
        01_test:
          command:
            !Sub |
              echo ${MyEndpoint} > /root/test.txt
```